# Does n-th invocation of Random.Next() with the same seed always produce the same number regardless of the .NET version?

Tags: c#, random, versioning

I am a newbie C# learner and building a system to generate problem sheets from an ordered set of questions. Each problem sheet has 30 question chosen randomly from the set of questions. Each problem sheet is  uniquely identified by an integer which is used as the seed value.

As I don't know the internal details of how random generator works, I want to know whether or not the `n`-th invocation of `Random.Next()` with the same seed will always produce the same number regardless of the .NET version.

The minimal working example is as follows.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int seed = 12345;
            Random rnd = new Random(seed);
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
                Console.WriteLine(rnd.Next());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you conclude from your output?

Comment: @gleng: Cannot make conclusion if I just use one version.

Comment: Even if the answer up until now may be "yes", I don't think you should rely on `Random` to produce non-random numbers. Also, wouldn't you have a chance to display the same question twice?

Comment: Why do you ask? No program design should depend on this question...

Comment: @C.Evenhuis: My idea is not to save the generated random in the database (to save more spaces). The generated numbers are important to reproduce the problem sheet in grading stage for example.

Comment: @RoyDictus: Almost funny I think. :-)

Comment: Write your own prng that has the property you desire.

Comment: @EricLippert: It becomes a hard task right now. How about just save the sequence in the database? It should be easier I think.

Comment: @StiffJokes: I can fit my own implementation of Random into a comment: `sealed class MyRandom
    {
        private int current;
        public MyRandom(int seed) { current = seed; }
        public int Next() { current = (current * 1140671485 + 12820163) & 0x7FFFFFFF; return current; }
    }` and still have 250 characters left. It's not a hard problem.

Comment: @EricLippert: Nice. But I am not sure it has reasonable randomness statistically. :-)

Comment: @StiffJokes: It has terrible randomness statistically, as do many prngs.  You are seeding a deterministic generator with an integer that can only have four billion possible values, so *automatically* you are limited to only four billion possible sequences of the gazillions available. All PRNGs that seed with integers have the property that they generate only a tiny fraction of the space of possibilities. Now, you have given no indication in your question that you require stronger randomness, so why complain about it?

Comment: @EricLippert: OK. Thank you so much. No more  complain after getting your very nice explanation. :-)

Comment: @EricLippert: Do you have any comment for my question in http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/222978/113457? Thank you in advance. My the same question posted to SO was on hold so I moved to programmers.sx.com.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **Notes to Callers**
>
> The implementation of the random number generator in the Random class is not guaranteed to remain the same across major versions of the .NET Framework. As a result, your application code should not assume that the same seed will result in the same pseudo-random sequence in different versions of the .NET Framework.

Comment: Sorry, so do you have suggestion how do I have to design my system described above? Do I also save the generated random number in a database such that I can retrieve in the future?

Comment: @StiffJokes - saving the sequence (if you have some form of storage, such as DB or even just a flat file) would be an easy way to do it. The alternative would be to obtain a specific implementation of a specific RNG that *is* deterministic and then always use that instead of the framework one.

Answer (score -3):

Yes! you have a possibility to get same random number will be generated if you provide same seed

```
Random rnd=new Random(5);
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rnd.Next());
            }

            Console.WriteLine(".....");

            Random rnd1 = new Random(5);

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rnd1.Next());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

############### The output

```
726643700
610783965
564707973
1342984399
995276750
1993667614
314199522
2041397713
1280186417
252243313
.....
726643700
610783965
564707973
1342984399
995276750
1993667614
314199522
2041397713
1280186417
252243313
```

Comment: But you used the same .NET version here!

Comment: i am just confused with your question, can you give some input and desired output samples

Comment: I want to know whether or not the n-th invocation of `Next()` (seeded with the same number) will always produce the same number no matter which .NET version we use. In other words, is the n-th invocation of `Next()` (with the same seed) is invariant under .NET versioning?

Comment: @BinsonEldhose The the question is about if he uses `Random` from .NET 1.1 and he uses `Random` from .NET 10000.5 (or any other future version that will be coming out), is he guaranteed that the same seed will produce the same output sequence. The documentation clearly says "No".

Comment: May be no guarantee to get same list of random number in different .net version with same seed. but i got same number of random number in different framework with same seed .. check this video   http://youtu.be/HVmh5ZXY86I